# How to toggle the Statusbar?

Tags: android, statusbar

I'm looking for a way to show and hide the statusbar with an `onClickListener`, but only showing it works.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
if (isStatusbarVisible)
    lp.flags = LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
else
    lp.flags = LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
isStatusbarVisible = !isStatusbarVisible;
```

Hiding the statusbar using `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` seems to work only if the flag is set before calling `setContentView()`.

Is there another way to hide the statusbar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple, clearing the `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` flag is all thats necessary:

```
if (isStatusBarVisible)
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
else
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for this solution, and finally came up with this implementation to toggle full screen on and off:

```
private void toggleFullscreen() {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
    attrs.flags ^= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
}
```

It uses bitwise XOR logic to toggle `FLAG_FULLSCREEN`.

Answer (score 1):

As we have all seen, the Android API is constantly changing.  Here's a more current answer to the question.

According to this doc:  https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

> **Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.1 and Higher**
>
> You can hide the status
> bar on Android 4.1 (API level 16) and higher by using
> setSystemUiVisibility(). setSystemUiVisibility() sets UI flags at the
> individual view level; these settings are aggregated to the window
> level. Using setSystemUiVisibility() to set UI flags gives you more
> granular control over the system bars than using WindowManager flags.
> This snippet hides the status bar:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Borrowing the groovy XOR from the other answers:

```
public void toggleFullscreen() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

    int uiOptions = decorView.getSystemUiVisibility();

    uiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;

    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

This does work (I am using it) and appears to function the same as the `getWindow().setAttributes()` solution, but it is the recommended way in the Developer docs.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better (does not require that boolean variable) toggle full screen method implementation:

```
private void toggleFullscreen() {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
    attrs.flags ^= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
}
```

It uses bitwise XOR logic to toggle `FLAG_FULLSCREEN`.