# How to hide StatusBar in Android 4

Tags: android, statusbar

How to hide StatusBar in Android 4:

[image: StatusBar in Android 4]

Help me, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to toggle the Statusbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856423/how-to-toggle-the-statusbar)

Answer (score 6):

The bar that is shown in the image in your question is called the system bar.

On devices with no hardware buttons the system bar will always be displayed if user input occurs. You can call [setSystemUiVisibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility%28int%29) with the flags [SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) and request the following window feature [FLAG_FULLSCREEN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_FULLSCREEN) via the [Window](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setUiOptions%28int,%20int%29). This should hide the system bar and make your view fullscreen as long as the user does not interact with the screen. If the user touches the screen the system bar will reappear to allow the user to use the home and back software keys.

If you have a view that the user will interact with but you want him not to be distracted by the system bar you can set the [SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE) flag. This should dim the system bar and make it less distracting.

Comment: I tried it and does not works on my motorola xoom 2 android 4.0.1. Are you sure this works? I call setSystemUiVisibility on the onCreate method.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Janusz. You can not get 100% true full screen in Android 4.0.

Use the following to dim the notification bar (aka. status bar, system bar)

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility
  (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

And use this to hide it

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility
  (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

And, if I guess right, you are trying to achieve a "kiosk mode". You can get a little help with an app named "surelock". This blocks all the "home" and "back" actions.

Comment: Surelock does much more than just adding these two flags. It completely hides the home, recent apps and screen capture buttons. Only home button is visible. And on rooted devices it can actually hide the complete statusbar and run all apps in full screen mode.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish a smooth experience without an intermediate "jerked" layout, here is the solution from API level 14.

```
final Window window = getWindow();
if (isFullScreen == true)
{
  window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  // This flag will prevent the status bar disappearing animation from jerking the content view
  window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
  window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
}
else
{
  window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
  window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
  window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you can hide it. just use following api in OnCreate() method

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: This will only hide the action bar.